# Parse Dashboard not showing cloud code & Jobs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I have cloned parse dahboard from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard. I have setup parse dashboard on local machine. it is runnning on port 4040 on my local machine but the dashboard which is opened is not displaying cloud code, jobs & app settings options which is displayed on parse.com. Please help me how can i see cloud code on parse dashbord & also tell me how can i deploy the parse dashboard to aws(remote server) so as other developer can also see the dashboard.